# Construct a modular expression (mod q) such that smallest root same as root of given expression (mod p)

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Apologies if I am not using the correct terms - I have never really studied modular arithmetic properly (Physics background). However, I am now playing with a cryptography problem and I have managed to reduce it down to the following:

Suppose you have a linear expression with two variables $x$ and $y$ in mod $p$, where $p$ is a large prime number:
$$ a\,x + b\,y + c = 0 \mod p$$
You know that this expression has roots $x_0 < p, y_0 < p$, i.e. I am not interested in the infinite set of roots $x = x_0 + np$ and $y = y_0 + np$ but only in the integer roots in the range $(0, p)$. You don't know the values of the roots, you just know they exist.

Can you construct a new expression in mod $q$ of the form:
$$ A(a, b, c, p)\,x + B(a, b, c, p)\,y + C(a, b, c, p) = 0 \mod q $$
such that it has the same roots $x_0, y_0$. You are free to choose any $q > p$ (for my particular needs, the bigger $q$, the better) and any functions $A, B, C$ (excluding of course the trivial $A = B = C = 0 \mod q$ case).

Comment: Would having $q=p^2$ be any use to you? Producing results always less than $p$ is difficult though.

Comment: $q = p^2$ would be perfect. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If $ax + by + c \equiv 0 \mod p$, then $amx + bmy + cm \equiv 0 \mod pm$ for any $m$, including $m = p$.

Comment: Thanks Paul. It's so obvious in hindsight...